# How to develop an android app using .Net Core 1.0?

Tags: .net, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, .net-core

I know that **.Net Core 1.0** is new released and is **cross-platform.**

Before deciding to go with .Net Core I want to clarification about how to do. I couldn't get satisfying information unfortunately.

So if I want to develop an android app using .Net Core 1.0, do I have to use **Xamarin**?

If so, how can I **make connection** with Xamarin while using .Net Core?

And .Net Core app can run on **Windows, Mac or Linux** but Xamarin apps cannot run on Linux. So as a result can my android app run on all platforms?

Thanks in advance.

**AS A RESULT:**

As @LexLi and @swick said:

*"If you write a library that targets .NET Standard Library, you will be able to use it from .Net Core, Xamarin and .Net Framework"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.Net Core 1.0 supports Windows, OS X and Linux, it does not support Android. So, if you want to write Android app, use Xamarin.

Comment: Oh yes.. when I saw [this link](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/06/net-core-1-0-released-now-officially-supported-by-red-hat/) it says .Net provides iOS and Android with Xamarin I thought that it is possible with .net core. Thank you.

Comment: @Hilal .NET Core is mainly an enabler for Windows/Linux/macOS applications, but Xamarin shares the same .NET Platform Standards, so you can safely share code among them.

Comment: @LexLi sorry for my ignorance but what should I understand from sharing code? Does it means when I write in Xamarin, can I use that code in .NET Core and get ability to run on Linux and Windows platform?

Comment: @Hilal If you write a library that targets [.NET Standard Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library), you will be able to use it from .Net Core, Xamarin and .Net Framework.

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you can develop cross platform applications (e.g. browser, Windows, Linux, Android etc) using .Net Core and Mono.